# Reversing $\sum_0^kx\cdot2^i$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algorithms

I'm trying to write an algorithm, and the easiest way I found for explaining the mathematical problem I'm facing is the following: Assume you have $x$ US dollars and you're gambling on a roulette.

Your gambling tactic is the following:
You always bet on black.

1. ball stops on black: you win - everyone's happy.
2. ball does not stop on black: you lose - you double your previous bet and put it on red again.

So what I'm looking for, is for a given starting amount of money and a number of bets that you're allowing yourself to lose in a strike , what will be my first bet? For example if I have 155USD and I'm willing to lose 5 times in a strike I will start with 5, 10, 20, 40, 80 $\rightarrow 5+10+20+40+80 = 155$

In mathematical means for given $Z$ and $k$ I need to find $x$:
$$\sum_0^kx\cdot2^i = Z$$

Comment: You can write $$Z=\sum_{i=0}^k x2^i=x\sum_{i=0}^k 2^i=x(2^{k+1}-1).$$

Comment: do you know what is $\sum_0^k 2^i$? if so you can just divide by that number

Comment: @IanMateus jesus, sometimes I complicate simple problems into matters I can not believe when I see the solution for them.

Comment: BTW this is called [martingale](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martingale_(betting_system)). The Wikipedia article contains a mathematical analysis of this system.

Comment: @MartinSleziak, Thanks, but it's  not about betting. I'm using it for an algorithm that needs to allocate "power", and I have a finite amount of "power" it can gain. If an action fails I want it to act next time with twice the "power" it used before. Best analogy I could find was a roulette.

Comment: Well, even if you do need it for other reasons, the mathematical analysis from the Wikipedia article might be useful/interesting for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in the comments, you can write $$Z=\sum_{i=0}^k x2^i=x\sum_{i=0}^k 2^i=x(2^{k+1}-1)\implies x=\frac{Z}{2^{k+1}-1}.$$ It seems you already know how to justify every step. You can ask for clarification if this is not the case.

Comment: I do, there's not much about it anyway. I guess it was the lack of hours of sleep that led to this funny question. Thank you anyway, you made it super clean within a second.